# Finding the value of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ defined by $a_n=(\frac{1}{2})^n$. For the sum of the first $20$ terms I was able to simplify this sum to the expression $2-(1/2)^{20}$. The desired expression in my manual is $2-(1/2)^{19}$.

I require assistance.

Answer (score 1):

For each natural number $n$, let $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n (\frac{1}{2})^i$. If we want $20$ terms, we have to consider $S_{19}$ (since $0$ is also in the enumeration).
Now, notice that in general we have that 
$$S_{n}-\frac{1}{2}S_n= 1-(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}.$$
Hence $S_n=\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=2-(\frac{1}{2})^n$. For $S_{19}$ we obtain $S_{19}=2-(\frac{1}{2})^{19}.$

Comment: How is 0 involved and could you please reexplain how only 19 terms are taken into account. I tank you for your assistance nonetheless.

Comment: Ah I got i! Thank http://math.stackexchange.com/users/155917/mathematician-42

Answer (score 1):

The first term is $(\frac{1}{2})^0=1$. The twentieth is $(\frac{1}{2})^{19}$. In binary, the sum is $1.1111111111111111111$.

Adding $(\frac{1}{2})^{19} =0.0000000000000000001$ gives 10.0000000000000000000, or in decimal, 2.

Thus, the sum is $2-(\frac{1}{2})^{19}$ as required.